# match period followed by digit zero to 2 times

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I am trying to write a regex that will match all of these:

```
1.5
2
2.7
3
3.5
3.5.0
3.6
4
```

My regex is failing to grab the 3.5.0 entry.  Regex101 shows it missing the second '.', but it does grab the '0'.

I am using: `(\d[\.\d]{0,2})`

I guess I am failing to execute:  a period followed by a single digit, repeated 0-2 times.

The full regex should be match a single digit, followed by a period followed by a single digit, repeated 0-2 times.

Comment: *zero* to two times would match `1.` as well, is that what you want?

Comment: Or perhaps your meaning is the pattern "period then digit" zero to two times?

Comment: How about `\d(\.\d){0,2}` ? `[\.\d]` matches a digit OR a period, not a period followed by a digit, I guess this is what you got wrong.

Comment: The regex should match a single digit only as well.  Note that '2', '3' and '4' are included above.

Comment: Yes, the pattern I commented above should match all those, notice the initial `\d` before the parenthesis.

Comment: Using Regex101 your pattern does not work.

Comment: It seems to work for me - https://regex101.com/r/ex9ymq/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^\d(?:\.\d){0,2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/VOXYko/1

Comment: That was it.  Much obliged.

Comment: @MarkS: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Characters in a pair of square brackets, known as a character set, matches just one character. You should enclose `\.\d` in parentheses instead of square brackets to actually group them as a sub-pattern for the following quantifier to repeat on.